Set up socket.IO within docker compose vue frontend and flask server
I have a docker compose with flask server and vue as frontend:
version: "3.9"

services:
  flask_app:
    container_name: flask_app
    image: dockerhub-flask_live_app:1.0.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"

  vue_frontend:
    container_name: vue_frontend
    image: node:latest
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./vue-frontend:/app
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    depends_on:
      - flask_app
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run dev"]

vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    proxy: {
      '/socket.io': {
        target: 'http://flask_app:4000',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})

and main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

import './assets/main.css';

const socket = io('http://flask_app:4000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Vue connected to server');
    socket.emit('register_vue');
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Vue disconnected from server');
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    socket.disconnect();
});

const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$socket = socket;

app.provide('socket', socket);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');

when I open my app in browser I got an error:
GET http://flask_app:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=vxp6ogxo net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
If I put localhost:4000 instead of flask_app:4000 everything is fine, but only on my local PC, when I put it on remote server and try to connect it does not work

Does "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend describe your problem?  I don't actually know how well the reverse-proxy approach I describe there will work with a websocket setup.

It worked! Thanks!
